# How to prevent Card from wrapping to next row with Semantic UI?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I want all of my card views to only display horizontally. Using the example from Semantic:

```
<div class="ui four cards">
 <div class="card">
   <div class="image">
     <img>
   </div>
   <div class="extra">
     Rating:
     <div class="ui star rating" data-rating="4"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
  ....
</div>
```

If I have more than four cards I want the 1st four cards to be sized equally and then the remaining cards to be accessible via a horizontal scrollbar. I don't want the other cards to be placed in rows below. How do I prevent the wrapping that Semantic does to the cards?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you resolve it?